# change the size of a button on a grid XAMARIN

Tags: xaml, xamarin, button, gridview, xamarin.forms

I need to change the size of a button that is inside a grid ....

[image: screenshot]

when adding the property HightRequest and WidthRequest this does not make any changes in my application ... this why it happens? What should I do to be able to modify the size of the buttons on my grid?

any help for me?

MyView.XAML:

```
 <StackLayout
            Padding="5">
            <SearchBar
                    Placeholder="Buscar..."              
                    BackgroundColor="White">
            </SearchBar>


            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="(1537) CLORO, GAS LICUADO"
                             VerticalOptions="Center">
                </Label>
                <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="VER"
                            BackgroundColor="Orange"
                            TextColor="White"
                    HeightRequest="5"
                    WidthRequest="5">  
                </Button>
                <Button
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Text="HDS"
                                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                TextColor="White">

                </Button>


                <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="(11) ACTION 707"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                    </Label>
                    <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="VER"
                            BackgroundColor="Orange"
                            TextColor="White">
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="HDS"
                            BackgroundColor="Blue"
                            TextColor="White">
                    </Button>

            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: row index 1 is out of grid row definition range (0-0)

Comment: Would you like to add another element <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" /> in my grid? or change the GRID.ROWS? @toumir

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you want to display the search result inside a list, each item list has a Label and two buttons ? or the row are fixed?

Comment: in this case ... the row is fixed @toumir

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackLayout
        Padding="5">
    <SearchBar
                Placeholder="Buscar..."              
                BackgroundColor="White">
    </SearchBar>


    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="(1537) CLORO, GAS LICUADO"
                         VerticalOptions="Center">
        </Label>
        <Button
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="VER"
                        BackgroundColor="Orange"
                        TextColor="White"
                HeightRequest="50"
                WidthRequest="120">
        </Button>
        <Button
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="HDS"
                            BackgroundColor="Blue"
                            TextColor="White"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="90">

        </Button>


        <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="(11) ACTION 707"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
        </Label>
        <Button
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="VER"
                        BackgroundColor="Orange"
                        TextColor="White">
        </Button>
        <Button
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="HDS"
                        BackgroundColor="Blue"
                        TextColor="White">
        </Button>

    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing `ColumnDefinition`'s widths in your Grid.
Also your second row is out of grid, because you only have one `RowDefinition`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a stack layout in the grid layout. Use the grid. Column/ grid.row to position the stack layout.Put the element you wish to resize within the stack layout which will accept width requests on the element within it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).